# This SQL query is taking too long

Tags: sql

This SQL query is taking too long

```
SELECT
s.State
, ServiceCenter
, s.LocationId
, LMG.dbo.ProperCase(LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' (' + convert(varchar,s.ClientId) + ')') as Client
, ISNULL(ul.ContractorName, ServiceCenter) as ContractorName
, InvoiceId as InvoiceNumber
, s.ItemDescription
, s.Quantity
--, s.Revenue
--, SUM(s.Quantity) as Quantity
, SUM(s.Quantity * s.UnitPrice) as Revenue
--, SUM(s.Quantity * s.Revenue) as Total
, SUM(Quantity * lxref.Amount) as ContractorPayment
, (SELECT InvoiceAmount FROM AG1.MAMOZI.dbo.tInvoices i WHERE s.InvoiceId = i.invoiceId AND DeletedStatus IS NULL) as InvoiceAmount
, (SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM AG1.MAMOZI.dbo.tPayments p WHERE s.InvoiceId = p.invoiceId AND DeletedStatus IS NULL) as PaymentAmount
, (SELECT PaymentType FROM #PaymentTypeGuardian pt WHERE pt.ClientId = s.ClientId AND pt.InvoiceId = s.InvoiceId) as PaymentType
, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AccountBalance) FROM [PLUSREPORT].Warehouse_LMG1.dbo.RptAccountBalance a WHERE a.CompanyId = 3 AND a.ClientId = CAST(s.ClientId as varchar(max))), 0) as AccountBalance
FROM #ServicePaymentGuardian s
INNER JOIN AG1.MAMOZI.dbo.tClient c on s.ClientId = c.ClientId
INNER JOIN DATABASESAVE.MAMO.org.LocationExtended le on s.LocationID = le.OrgDatabaseid
INNER JOIN DATABASESAVE.MAMO.jur.Location ul on le.LocationId = ul.LocationId AND ul.LocationTypeid = 2
INNER JOIN DATABASESAVE.MAMO.base.Jurisdiction uj on ul.JurisdictionId = uj.JurisdictionId AND uj.CompanyId = 3
INNER JOIN DATABASESAVE.MAMO.jur.LocationServicePaymentXref lxref on ul.LocationId = lxref.LocationId and s.ServicePaymentId = lxref.ServicePaymentId

GROUP BY
s.State
, ServiceCenter
, s.LocationId
, s.ClientId
, c.LastName
, c.FirstName
, s.InvoiceId
, s.Quantity
, s.ItemDescription
, s.ServicePaymentId
, ul.ContractorName
Order by State, ServiceCenter, InvoiceNumber, LastName, FirstName, ItemDescription
```

Comment: use `explain` for optimization. or share the whole tables structure.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is _query language, not the name of  a specific database product)

Comment: Joins instead of those correlated sub-queries?

Comment: What does the temp table do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. see execution plan - maybe you need to add indexes
2. run query without sub-queries and see how long it will take then
3. try to split query to smaller parts (and run it separately) to find out which part slows query down